# A function $f$ twice differentiable, such that $f$ and $f''$ are bounded imply $f'$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ twice differentiable. Suppose $A$, $C$ in $(0,\infty)$ such that for each $x>0$ we have $|f(x)|<A$ and $|f''(x)|<C$. Prove that for each $x>0$ and each $h>0$ we have $|f'(x)| \le (A/h)$+$Ch$

Using Mean Value Theorem

$f'(x)-f'(y) = f''(c) (x-y)$ for some $c$. Since $f''$ is bounded by $C$

$f'(x)-f'(y) \le  C (x-y)$. Letting $h=x-y$ we got

$f'(x) \le  Ch + f'(y)$

How can I bound $f'(y)$ by $A/h$ to obtain the desired bound??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f$ is twice differentiable, we can use the MVT to write

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac12 f''(\xi)h^2$$

for some $x<\xi<x+h$.  Rearraning we see that

$$f'(x)=\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right)-\frac12 f''(\xi)h$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
|f'(x)|&\le\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|+\left|\frac12 f''(\xi)\right|h \\
&\le \frac{1}{h}\left(|f(x+h)|+|f(x)|\right)+\frac12 h|f''(\xi)|\\
&\le 2(A/h)+\frac{1}{2}Ch
\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you get the first equation from the mvt?

Comment: @Linom Are you not familiar with the extended MVT?

Comment: I'm not actually, let me google it