# Mean value theorem for twice differentiable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ be a twice differentiable function. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210943/a-function-f-twice-differentiable-such-that-f-and-f-are-bounded-imply) answer, it is asserted that the MVT lets one write $$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac12 f''(\xi)h^2$$ for some $\xi\in (x,x+h)$.

It is not clear to me why this should be the case. Using the MVT, one can write $f''(\xi)h=f'(x+h)-f'(x)$ for some $\xi\in (x,x+h)$. Using that, the claim rephrases to $$f(x+h)=f(x)+\frac{1}{2}f'(x)h+\frac{1}{2}f'(x+h)h$$ and I don't see why that should hold.

I'm sure I'm being stupid, therefore I much welcome clarification.

Comment: Check [Taylor's Thereom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic arguments of the exact proof (which I do not give here) that this works, go as follows: [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) says that $$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\underbrace{\frac12f''(x)h^2+ο(h^2)}$$ If we replace $x$ with $ξ$ (where $ξ$ is given by the MVT) in the underlined term we can get rid of the remainder $ο(h^2)$ and achieve an exact calculation of $f(x+h)$: 
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac12f''(ξ)h^2$$ Why then the approximation in the first place? The MVT says there exists such an $ξ$ but does not give a way to find it, so the approximation in Taylor's theorem is indeed useful.

Answer (score 0):

What the answer uses is not really Lagrange's M.V.T. but rather [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), that too upto the third term i.e. the second derivative since it has been explicitly mentioned that the function is twice differentiable.

As for your second part i.e.

> It is not clear to me why this should be the case. Using the MVT, one can write $f''(\xi)h=f'(x+h)-f'(x)$ for some $\xi\in (x,x+h)$. Using that, the claim rephrases to $$f(x+h)=f(x)+\frac{1}{2}f'(x)h+\frac{1}{2}f'(x+h)h$$ and I don't see why that should hold.

There is no valid reason why this should not hold. If you arrange the expression a little bit, 
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+\frac{1}{2}f'(x)h+\frac{1}{2}f'(x+h)h$$ or 
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{1}{2}f'(x)+\frac{1}{2}f'(x+h)$$
$$2f'(\alpha)=f'(x)+f'(x+h)$$
for some suitable $\alpha \in (x,x+h)$

So there is nothing wrong with this.